# Java. Creating server-client application

Tags: java, glassfish, client-server

I want to make application  with server, web-client and desktop-client.

Can I use Glassfish's app for this kind of server or only as web-client?

Comment: Specifically to your question, YES. You can use Glassfish as a web-server. An Application Server is a superset of a web-server.

Comment: @unihedron it is about the Java EE capabilities of a specific application server.  Sounds fine to me.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ah, that comment was pre-edit. It's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In Java EE a desktop client (which can exchange data easily with the application server) is called an enterprise application client.

See https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html for a short tutorial with Netbeans.

A side note: if you want to work a lot with Glassfish consider doing it in Netbeans. The integration is much better than in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! Don't have rep for +1. )

Comment: No need. Hope you make it work - writing programs to run on multiple machines is more difficult.